# mock Gson().toJson inside android test

Tags: java, android, mockito, gson, android-testing

I'm creating a test for activity where there is a line:

```
Logger.i("Response", new Gson().toJson(response));
```

and it crashes with the message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: web.services.Response. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

I tried to add the following line to the test but it doesn't help:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(mock(Response.class).getClass(), new ClassTypeAdapter()).create();
```

P.S. I can not use powerMock to mock Gson final class.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You could make your own interface `IJsonParser` and create an implementation which uses Gson, which you would use in the app. Then in your tests you can mock the interface you created instead of the final class.

Comment: unfortunately I can not fix the code.

Comment: @KubaSpatny and I'm testing activity. Where should I write the implementation for the test? Or you meant to move the main logic to presenter and test the presenter?

Comment: Oh I didn't read that thoroughly, I thought you're running it as a unit/instrumentation test. The test implementation could be written in your test activity as inner static class to keep it tidy. But the MVP or MVVM architectures definitely help when testing. As you said, if the logic wasn't in an activity but in a presenter, you could simply run it as a unit test locally on your machine.

Comment: @KubaSpatny  Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. the Question is - where to write the implementation of the interface IJsonParser if all my code is in only one activity? As I understand I have to move it away from my activity because it will contain Gson class.